# OpenLayers button event

Tags: openlayers-2, events

I'm using OpenLayers 2:10 Beginners Guide ebook. This code is APRA create a button click event in an opacity and zoom the map. But already rewritten several times and does not work. Nothing appears.

Where is the error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8' />
 <title>My OpenLayers Map</title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
 <style type='text/css'>
    /*Custom Button*/
    .olControlCustomButtonItemInactive {
        background:#22dd22;
        border:5px solid #202020;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 28px;
        width: 28px;
    }
 </style>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 var map;
 //Função a ser chamada para criar o mapa na leitura da página
 function init() {
//Cria o objeto map     
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {});     
//Cria a primeira camada usando o serviço WMS, explicitamnete definida como base
    var wms_layer_map = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        'Base layer',
        'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
        {layers: 'basic'},
        {isBaseLayer: true}
        );

//Adiciona as camadas ao mapa em uma martriz de objetos de camada
    map.addLayers([wms_layer_map);
 }

 //Função do botão para mudar opacidade e zoom ao evento do click
var custom_button_func = function(){
//Get a random coordinate from -90 to 90
var random_lon = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) - 180;
var random_lat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) - 90;
if(map.layers[0].opacity === 1){
//If the layer opacity is 1 (fully opaque), then change it
and zoom
map.layers[0].setOpacity(.5);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(random_lon,
random_lat), 3);
}
else{
//If the layer opacity is anything but 1, change it and
zoom
map.layers[0].setOpacity(1);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(random_lon,
random_lat), 3);
}
};


//Cria o botão com a chamada para a função
var my_button = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
    displayClass: 'olControlCustomButton',
    trigger: custom_button_func
});

//Painel onde será exibido o botão
var control_panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({});

//Chama o addControl
control_panel.addControls([
    custom_button
    ]);

//Adiciona o painel ao mapa
map.addControl(control_panel);

//Move o mapa
control_panel.moveTo(new OpenLayers.Pixel(450,0));

 //Informações do centro do mapa
 if(!map.getCenter()){
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload='init();'> <!-- Chama a função js init() --> 
<!--Elemento HTML onde o mapa é exibido -->
 <div id='map_element' style='width: 500px; height: 500px;'>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have repaired your code, but first I want to list all the found errors, so that you can avoid them in the future:

- the `init()` function is incredibly small so it is not surprising that nothing works:

[image]

- in the above `init()` function, there is a missing square bracket, on the last line of code.
- portions of the comments are mixed with the code:

[image]

- sometimes the custom button is called `my_button`, and other times `custom_button`;

My advice for you is to use a [Javascript IDE with code completion and syntax checking](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/587/javascript-ide-with-code-completion-and-syntax-checking).
This way you'll be able to easily identify the errors.

Bellow is the repaired code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset = 'utf-8' />
    <title> My OpenLayers Map </title>
    <script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'http://openlayers.org/api/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js'></script>

    <style type = 'text/css'>
        /*Custom Button*/
        .olControlCustomButtonItemInactive {
            background:#22dd22;
            border:5px solid #202020;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 28px;
            width: 28px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
        //Variável map
        var map;
        //Funçao a ser chamada para criar o mapa na leitura da página
        function init() {
            //Cria o objeto map     
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {});
            //Cria a primeira camada usando o serviço WMS, explicitamnete definida como base
            var wms_layer_map = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                'Base layer',
                'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
                {layers: 'basic'},
                {isBaseLayer: true}
            );
            //Adiciona as camadas ao mapa em uma martriz de objetos de camada
            map.addLayers([wms_layer_map]);
            //Funçao do botao para mudar opacidade e zoom ao evento do click
            var my_button_func = function(){
                //Get a random coordinate from -90 to 90
                var random_lon = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) - 180;
                var random_lat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) - 90;
                if (map.layers[0].opacity === 1){
                    //If the layer opacity is 1 (fully opaque), then change it and zoom
                    map.layers[0].setOpacity(.5);
                    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(random_lon, random_lat), 3);
                } else {
                    //If the layer opacity is anything but 1, change it and zoom
                    map.layers[0].setOpacity(1);
                    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(random_lon, random_lat), 3);
                }
            };
            //Cria o botao com a chamada para a funçao
            var my_button = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
                displayClass: 'olControlCustomButton',
                trigger: my_button_func,
            });
            //Painel onde será exibido o botao
            var control_panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({});
            //Chama o addControl
            control_panel.addControls([
                my_button
            ])

            //Adiciona o painel ao mapa
            map.addControl(control_panel);
            //Move o mapa
            control_panel.moveTo(new OpenLayers.Pixel(450, 0));
            //Informaçoes do centro do mapa
            if (!map.getCenter()){
                map.zoomToMaxExtent();
            }
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload = 'init();'> <!-- Chama a funçao js init() -->
    <!--Elemento HTML onde o mapa é exibido -->
    <div id = 'map_element' style = 'width: 500px; height: 500px;'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is a browser screenshot:

[image]